# How does selenium compare elements?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

In the recent version of Protractor, [`equals()` method was added on an `ElementFinder` object](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/76861fdc4c57c2aaa984e05e46ff9789ce750260). The method in turn calls the WebDriverJS's `WebElement.equals()` method:

```
return webdriver.WebElement.equals(this.getWebElement(),
    element.getWebElement ? element.getWebElement() : element);
```

How does the `equals()` method work? How does it check if elements are equal or not? Simply checking the `innerHTML` is, obviously, not enough since two different elements can be represented identically on a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.equals()` method of the `WebDriverJS`, javascript selenium bindings, at first, *compares `WebElement` IDs* (documented in the webdriver spec [here](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#elements)), which are retrieved by the [`getId()`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js#L1777) method:

```
var ids = [a.getId(), b.getId()];
return webdriver.promise.all(ids).then(function(ids) {
    // If the two element's have the same ID, they should be considered
    // equal. Otherwise, they may still be equivalent, but we'll need to
    // ask the server to check for us.
    if (ids[0][webdriver.WebElement.ELEMENT_KEY] ==
        ids[1][webdriver.WebElement.ELEMENT_KEY]) {
      return true;
    }

    // ...
}
```

If IDs are equal, two elements are considered equal. But,if they are not, it does not mean the elements are not equal and, in this case, the concept of the [DOM Node Equality](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-equals) comes into play through the [`elementEquals()` wrapped method](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/javascript/firefox-driver/js/wrappedElement.js#L44). The logic behind the node equality check is based on comparing the node types, attributes, namespaces, number of children etc.